# Help with trig sub integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I've gone over my work twice, and while I dropped a negative the first time, I believe that my work is sound. Webwork is not accepting it, however.

Here is the problem and my solution. Sorry for bad handwriting

[image]

Comment: I assume you are differentiating w.r.t. (what looks like) $\alpha$?

Comment: Oh, theta, yes. Or alpha, no difference. The topic of the week is trig sub, so that is what I am doing.

Comment: Can you clarify what the denominator is? $\sqrt{4x - x^2}$ or $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$?

Comment: The former, yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the draft is crappy.

Comment: @mtlchk You should really try and copy your work into the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\int\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{4x - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\equiv\int\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{4 - (x - 2)^2}}\,\mathrm dx$$

Let $x - 2 = 2\sin(u)\implies\mathrm dx = 2\cos(u)\,\mathrm du$. Therefore,

$$\begin{align}\int\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{4 - (x - 2)^2}}\,\mathrm dx&\equiv\int\dfrac{2\cos(u)(2\sin(u) + 2)^2}{\sqrt{4 - 4\sin(u)}}\,\mathrm du \\ &\stackrel{\sin^2(u) + \cos^2(u) = 1}=4\int(\sin(u) + 1)^2\,\mathrm du \\ &= 4\int\sin^2(u) + 2\sin(u) + 1\,\mathrm du \\ &=4\int\sin^2(u)\,\mathrm du + 8\int\sin(u)\,\mathrm du + 4\int1\,\mathrm du\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That is some pretty fancy mathing. I wish I was so good at completing squares since it is a useful skill. Any suggestions on how to learn?

Comment: @mtlchk Practice.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=2\sin{t}$.

Thus, $$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=\int\frac{x^2-4+4}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=4\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx-\int\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=$$
$$=4\arcsin\frac{x}{2}-4\int\cos^2tdt=4\arcsin\frac{x}{2}-2\int(1+\cos2t)dt.$$
Can you end it now?

Also, let $x-2=v$.

Thus, we can use the similar way: $$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}dx=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}}dx=\int\frac{v^2+4v+4}{\sqrt{4-v^2}}dv=$$
$$=\int\frac{v^2-4+4v+8}{\sqrt{4-v^2}}dv=\int\frac{4v}{\sqrt{4-v^2}}dv-\int\sqrt{4-v^2}dv+8\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-v^2}}dv.$$

Comment: I believe the denominator is $\sqrt{4{\color{red}{x}} - x^2}$, not $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$.

Comment: @an4s  Maybe. I just saw a first step of the topic-starter's solution